# Laravel 4 showing all field from one to one relationship in

Tags: php, laravel, relationship

I'm trying to show all field of the chosen row from one to one relationship...

Route

```
Route::get('relasi-pasien', function()
{
$pasien = PasienIri::where('no_ipd', '=', '100')->first();

foreach($pasien->keadaanumum as $temp)
    {
      echo'<li> 
      Name  : '.$temp->name.
     'Tekdar: '.$temp->tekdar.
     'Nadi  : '.$temp->nadi.
     '</li>';
    }
});
```

Relation at PasienIri's model

```
public function keadaanumum()
{
    return $this->hasOne('KeadaanUmum', 'no_ipd');
}
```

Relation at KeadaanUmum's Model

```
public function pasieniri()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('PasienIri', 'no_ipd');
}
```

When I used that way, it showed error: 'Trying to get property of non-object'

But if I just trying to show only one of the field, it works,

showing one field:

```
Route::get('relasi-pasien', function()
{
$pasien = PasienIri::where('no_ipd', '=', '100')->first();

return $pasien->keadaanumum->name;
});
```

anyone could help me to show all field with one to one relationship

or I really have to change it to one to many relationship? cause if I change it to one to many relationship, it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach($pasien->keadaanumum as $temp)
```

Since this is a one-to-one relationship, you shouldn't need to `foreach` over it.  Try instead this:

```
echo 
  '<li>' . 
    'Name  : ' . $pasien->keadaanumum->name .
    'Tekdar: ' . $pasien->keadaanumum->tekdar .
    'Nadi  : ' . $pasien->keadaanumum->nadi .
  '</li>'
;
```

You could do as you say and change it to a one-to-many relationship, but you will most likely need to remove the link to your `KeadaanUmum` table from your `PasienIri` table, since that implies that it will only match with a single related entry.  This however totally depends on whether you actually want to do that (allow many `KeadaanUmum`s for each `PasienIri`).